# Hide Dashboard in Lion 10.7

Tags: cocoa

In 10.7.2 lion, i can hide widgets by typing in the command -

```
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -boolean YES
killall Dock
```

But the above does not seem to be working on 10.7. Any idea what could be wrong ?.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: This worked for me with 10.8.